# Does any Lightroom gallery make use of Lightroom’s tags for navigation?

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-6

Does any built-in Lightroom gallery or some third-party gallery support Lightroom’s tags? It would offer more navigation possibilities for those looking at my galleries. I am running Lightroom 6.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. By "Lightroom's tags" do you mean the EXIF keywords? And are the navigation possibilities you imagine that the user could click those keywords/tags to navigate to other photos with the same keywords?

Comment: @DanWolfgang I mean those keywords that can be added in the library view. When I export files, these are written as IPTC metadata. Regarding the navigation, I mean grouping photos by keywords.

Comment: Alloy Photo has a plugin to publish to Gallery hosting services; it claims support for keywords. Or try the Turning Gate plugins.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean online gallery, certainly not Adobe's Revel. IIRC it doesn't even SHOW exif keywords.

Flickr does a decent job with keywords. It shows them, and clicking one as a button takes you to not only all your photos with that keyword, but everyone else's, in two separate groups (perhaps there's a way to limit the filter to only your own photos).

Comment: By "gallery" I mean those Web galleries created from the Web module. I don’t look for services like Flickr.